# Polymer Routing Not Routing

Tags: polymer

I am trying to create a simple app. It has a profile button, and when the profile button is pressed I would like it to be routed to the Userprofile page. I am quite new to Polymer and routing in general, and would appreciate if some could advice what I am doing wrong. Here is my code snippet. I am using polymer 1.6, and using app-route, app-location. I have defined them, and am using iron-pages to select the route (NOT SURE IF THAT IS CORRECT).

**cst-tririga-ux.html**

```
<!-- POLYMER IMPORTS -->
<link rel='import' href='../paper-icon-button/paper-icon-button.html'>
<link rel="import" href="../paper-input/paper-input.html">
<link rel="import" href="../paper-badge/paper-badge.html">

<!-- APP TOOLBAR -->
<link rel="import" href='app-layout.html'>

<!-- IRON IMPORTS -->
<link rel="import" href="../iron-icons/iron-icons.html">
<link rel="import" href="../iron-pages/iron-pages.html">

<!-- TRIRIGA IMPORTS -->
<link rel="import" href="../triplat-view-behavior/triplat-view-behavior.html">
<link rel="import" href="../triplat-signout-button/triplat-signout-button.html">
<link rel="import" href="../triplat-ds/triplat-ds.html">


<!-- CUSTOM COMPONENTS -->
<link rel="import" href="profile/user-profile.html">
<link rel="import" href="notifications/notifications-view.html">


<dom-module id="cst-tririga-ux">
  <template>
    <style>
      paper-input-container.my-class {
        --paper-input-container-color: red;
        --paper-input-container-focus-color: blue;
        --paper-input-container-invalid-color: green;
        --paper-input-container-input-color: black;
      }

      paper-badge {
      --paper-badge-margin-left: -8px;
      --paper-badge-margin-bottom: -12px;
      --paper-badge-background: #D50000;
      };

      html, body {
          margin: 0;
          font-family: 'Roboto', 'Noto', sans-serif;
          -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
          background: #f1f1f1;
          max-height: 368px;
        }

        paper-icon-button {
          --paper-icon-button-ink-color: white;
        }

        paper-icon-button + [main-title] {
          margin-left: 24px;
        }        

        app-header {
          @apply(--layout-fixed-top);
          color: #fff;
          --app-header-background-rear-layer: {
            background-color: #ef6c00;
          };
        }

        app-drawer {
          --app-drawer-scrim-background: rgba(0, 0, 100, 0.8);
          --app-drawer-content-container: {
            background-color: #f4f6f7;
          }
        }

        app-toolbar {
          /* Toolbar is the main header, so give it some color */
          background-color: #1E88E5;
          font-family: 'Roboto', Helvetica, sans-serif;
          color: white;
          --app-toolbar-font-size: 24px;
        }
      </style>
      <!-- DECLARATIONS -->
      <triplat-ds id="currentDS" name="currentUser" data="{{currentUser}}"></triplat-ds>
      <triplat-ds id="myNotificationsDS" name="myNotifications" data="{{myNotifications}}"></triplat-ds>
      <app-location use-hash-as-path route="{{route}}"></app-location>
      <app-route route="{{route}}" pattern="/:view" data="{{routeData}}" tail="{{subroute}}"></app-route>

      <body>        
        <app-header reveals>
          <app-toolbar>           
            <paper-icon-button icon="menu" onclick="drawer.toggle()"></paper-icon-button>
            <div main-title>Spork</div>
            <paper-icon-button icon="account-circle" id="profile" on-tap="redirectToProfile"></paper-icon-button>
            <paper-icon-button icon="mail" id="notifications"></paper-icon-button>
            <paper-badge for="notifications" label="{{myNotifications.length}}"></paper-badge>
            <triplat-signout-button></triplat-signout-button>
           </app-toolbar>
          <iron-pages selected="[[routeData.view]]" attr-for-selected="name">
            <user-profile name="profile" route="{{subroute}}"></user-profile>
            <notifications-view name="notifications" route="{{subroute}}"></notifications-view>
          </iron-pages>          
        </app-header>
        <app-drawer id="drawer" swipe-open>
          <paper-menu selected="0">
            <paper-item>Item One</paper-item>
            <paper-item>Item Two</paper-item>
            <paper-item>Item Three</paper-item>
          </paper-menu>
        </app-drawer>        
      </body>
    </template>
<dom-module>
<script>
  Polymer({
    is: "cst-tririga-ux",
    behaviors: [TriPlatViewBehavior],
    // Display in browser title.
    ready: function() {
      var __dictionary__title =  "Prudential CRE";
      document.title = __dictionary__title;     
    },
    redirectToProfile : function(el) {
      var currUser = this.currentUser;
      location.pathname = "/#/profile"      
    }        
  });
</script>
```

The user-profile and the notifications-view are just templates. Currently, when I am clicking on the my-profile button. Nothing seems to be happening. Not sure what I am doing wrong. Here is my user-profile.html

```
<dom-module id="user-profile">
    <template>
        <div>My user page</div>
    </template>
</dom-module>
<script>
    Polymer({

        is: "user-profile", 

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Try to add import for `app-location`, `app-route` and close `dom-module` tag in main file. You use a right approach with `app-route` and `iron-pages`

Comment: Thank you for your response, unfortunately it did not work. I had app-layout.html which has all the imports. And I did close the dom-module. Not sure what is going on.